# Parsing data in txt file to table (dataframe) in R

Tags: r, parsing, read.table, columnsorting

I'm very new here and I'm also new in working with R programme.
I would like to ask, please, how to parse out the data from a text file to the table in "Environment" section.
Specifically, I have no idea of how from the measured temperature data from each Sensor in the file ["**teplota_19-10-2020**"](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fBD9ta7p0D2Iz4uyPyCd5xv4b5Kxf5ZQ/view?usp=sharing) to create columns to make it look the same as in a table in the result picture "**tab2**" here:

[image: Result table of measured temperatures]

Thank you very much for considering of helping me.

Comment: That is a fixed width file and R comes with the `read.fwf` function to read those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to create a data frame containing the desired output you need to read the file and do some transformation.
Aparently "cas - hodiny" translate from Czech into English as "time - hours".

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(purrr)

fl = read.csv2("teplota_19-10-2020.txt", sep = ",")
names(fl) <- paste0("col", 1:10)
df <- fl %>% mutate(`hour:min:sec` = str_split(col1, " ") %>% map_chr(.,1),
                sensor1 = str_split(col1, " ")%>% map_chr(.,3),
                sensor2 = str_split(col2, " ") %>% map_chr(.,3),
                sendorOW1 = str_split(col3, " ") %>% map_chr(.,3),
                sendorOW2 = str_split(col4, " ") %>% map_chr(.,3),
                setpoint = str_split(col5, " ") %>% map_chr(.,3),
                ouput = str_split(col6, " ") %>% map_chr(.,3),
                P = str_split(col7, " ") %>% map_chr(.,3),
                `I` = str_split(col8, " ") %>% map_chr(.,3),
                `D` = str_split(col9, " ") %>% map_chr(.,3),
                ModRizeiTeploty = str_split(col10, " ") %>% map_chr(.,3)
 ) 

 df$`cas - hudiny` <- sapply(str_split(df$`hour:min:sec`, ":"), 
                             function(i) sum(as.numeric(i)/c(1, 60, 3600))
                             )
 df <- df %>% select("hour:min:sec", `cas - hudiny`, sensor1,  sensor2, sendorOW1, sendorOW2, setpoint, ouput, P, I, D, ModRizeiTeploty)
```

[image]